# Instal ejabberd on centos 6.7 - epel is enabled still No package ejabberd available

Tags: installation, centos6, yum, ejabberd, epel

I am trying to install ejabberd on my centos 6.7. As I googled I found that I need to enable EPEL which I did still there is no success.

Out put for **yum repolist**

```
[root@static ~]# yum repolist
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.saglayici.com
* epel: epel.mirror.srv.co.ge
* extras: mirror.saglayici.com
* updates: mirror.saglayici.com
repo id          repo name                                                 status
base             CentOS-6 - Base                                           6575
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           11765
extras           CentOS-6 - Extras                                           35
updates          CentOS-6 - Updates                                         297
repolist: 18672
```

Can any one help me please. Or suggest me some other way to install ejabberd.

I have also **stoped** **iptable**

output of **yum install ejabberd**

```
[root@static ~]# yum install ejabberd
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            | 5.5 kB     00:00     
* base: mirror.saglayici.com
* epel: epel.mirror.srv.co.ge
* extras: mirror.saglayici.com
* updates: mirror.saglayici.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 5.7 MB     00:04     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
No package ejabberd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: What output do you get from `yum install ejabberd`?

Comment: @sborsky Thanks for reply... I added out put of yum install ejabbered in question.

Comment: Whatever you read on the Internet is wrong. There is no ejabberd package in CentOS or EPEL.

Comment: Looks like there is no package for CentOS through EPEL anymore. But: You could just download it directly from here (and not use yum): https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should try the installer or experimental package from ProcessOne: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/